# What is UIE timer in RTC?

Tags: real-time

I am trying to apply a patch that enables UIE timer but I don't understand what UIE stands for and what's the use of it.

https://lore.kernel.org/linux-rtc/20191021155631.3342-1-alexandre.belloni@bootlin.com/T/

Comment: these may help ... https://linux.die.net/man/4/rtc 
... https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/rtc/Kconfig

Comment: what does it stands for?

Comment: did you look at the first link? ... it says `RTC_UIE_ON, RTC_UIE_OFF
Enable or disable the interrupt on every clock update` ....  what words start with U, I and E?

Comment: My guess is update the clock on Interrupt enable?

Comment: no ... three words only ... the setting enables or disables an interrupt ... it does not update the clock ... update interrupt enable ... the documentation explains what the update interrupt is

Comment: I stands for Interrupt, E stands for Enable and I don't know what U stands for?

Comment: update interrupt enable